# How Do I send A Text Via SmsManager?

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

so I have a button that when clicked, I want to send a text message. To who, is specified by the editText. When I use the app, it says that the text is sent, however when I check in my messaging app it shows that nothing sent. How do I remedy this?

Example Number: "8667404531" (This is a bot hotline for example)

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String myNum = editText.getText().toString();


    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(myNum, null, "Wake Up!", null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you add permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
 in your manifest ?

Comment: @ElMaravilla it's not enough to set manifest permission, you should also call checkSelfPermission() and receive positive respond in its callback method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have set this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Secondly, you should check self permission before you can send any messages. You can achieve that with `checkSelfPermission()` call and corresponding `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback.

Check out this code below, it contains important parts related to requesting permissions from the device. This code below is a complete example of `Activity` for sending SMS from your device:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText number, text;
    Button send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            }
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phoneNumber = number.getText().toString();
                String messageText = text.getText().toString();

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageText, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 1:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission not granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```